# Legend colours to call on dictionary R

Tags: r, legend

I have a plot which plots points with a particular symbol and color. I want my legend to show the exact same colors and symbols as those in the plot. I can do this manually, but I have over 50 plots to generate and data is going to be conually updated so I would like to automate the process. I tried to create a dictionary and wanted to search the dictionary. If the value was found in `levels(Color_test)`, then color the symbol in legend the same as outlined in the dictionary.
My legend code is as follows:

```
legend(legend_X, legend_Y,
    xjust=x_adj, yjust=y_adj,
    levels(Color_test), 
    col=Labels.col,
    pch=Labels.sym,
    horiz=FALSE)
```

Comment: A simple example would help us understand how you have this set up already. At the moment we would be making a "stab in the dark."

Answer (score 0):

May be what you are looking for is some kind of merging your data with the dictionary. Here is how it is done with only colors as it is just an example

```
data <- data.frame(type = sample(letters[1:3],20,replace=T),
                   x = runif(20),
                   y = runif(20))
dict <- data.frame(type = letters[1:4],
                   color = c("red","green","blue","black"))
plot(data$x, data$y, col = merge(data,dict)$color)
legend("topleft",legend=dict$type, col=dict$color, pch=1)
```

Easily you can modify the legend so that is justs displays the actually used colors.

```
data_dict <- merge(data,dict)
plot(y~x, col=color, data=data_dict, pch=as.vector(type))
legend("topleft",legend=unique(data_dict$type), col=unique(data_dict$color), pch=1)
```